# Como formatar uma célula a partir do código RGB contido na própria célula

Tags: microsoft-excel, rgb

É possível alterar, a cor de fundo de uma célula a partir de um código `RGB` ou `hexadecimal` escrito como texto na própria célula?
Vamos supor que escrevo `255,0,0` na `célula A1` e quando pressiono `enter` o fundo da célula muda para vermelho!

Comment: Não tive como testar a função em casa... mas amanhã testo e atualizo aqui se for o caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terá de usar o VBA para isso, teste o código abaixo para a célula A1:

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(127,187,199)
```

Se desejar fazer isso para todas as células, terá de usar a função *Worksheet_Change* de todas as planilhas algo do tipo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim clrCor As Long
Dim arrCores() As String

    arrCores = Split(Target.Text, ",")
    clrCor = RGB(CInt(arrCores(0)), CInt(arrCores(1)), CInt(arrCores(2)))

    Target.Interior.Color = clrCor

End Sub
```

**Edição 1**

Respondendo ao comentário abaixo...

Se tiver as cores pré-definidas em uma tabela, conseguirá fazer essa formatação condicional (com limitações das cores definidas). Algo do tipo:

```
| Tabela de Cores |
| Azul            |
| Vermelho        |
| Verde           |
```

Nesta tabela vc irá criar uma lista pré-definida (ex. lstCor).

Na tabela que deseja formatar de forma condicional, irá colocar validação da célula com lista. Pra que a escolha seja sempre dentro das opções já definidas.

Na sua formatação condicional irá vincular o valor dá célula ativa, e conforme o resultado *Azul* irá formatar com o Azul, neste caso terá de ter uma regra de formatação para cada cor cadastrada.

[Aqui](https://github.com/excelguru/controle-obrigacao/raw/master/Controle%20de%20Obrigacoes.xlsx) tem um modelo de formatação avançada com tabela de dados, conforme exposto.

Caso tenha dúvida em como fazer lista e validação, clique [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1zcWQAB4PA).

> **Observação**:
>
> Essa mesma ideia de usar tabelas poderia ser estendida ao utilizar uma
>   tabela com todas as cores RGB. Só que:
>
> 1. A combinação de valores na tabela vai ser enorme (256³ itens na lista);
> 2. Como a formatação condicional requer que a cor seja manualmente especificada em uma regra, o número de regras também vai ser enorme (igualmente,
>      256³ regras);
>
> Ou seja, é mais simples e fácil fazer em VBA.

**Edição 2**

Testei a fórmula VBA e atualizei para funcionar corretamente, lembrando que deve-se fazer alguns testes com o *Target.text* pois se não contiver o formato desejado irá resultar em erro.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: A minha curiosidade estava focada em fazer algo como descrito sem recorrer ao VBA. Talvez uma opção qualquer da formatação condicional.

Comment: Eu posso editar, sem problemas. Farei isso. AP é "Autor da Pergunta" (meio que veio do SOEn, onde eles usam OP pra "Original Poster", ou autor da postagem original). Desculpe, eu esqueço as vezes que nem todo mundo já entende essas abreviações. rs :)

Comment: Adicionei na sua resposta a minha sugestão. Também apaguei os meus comentários (para não poluir mais o conteúdo). Por favor, faça o mesmo. Depois eu venho aqui e apago este também. :)